# Условие для двух почти одинаковых переменных js

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня две почти одинаковых инпута, отличаются идентификатором и значением. Вот у меня такой код:

```
var label  = $('#label_1').val(); // value="1"
var label  = $('#label_2').val(); // value="2"

var postData = {label: label};
```

В js не разбираюсь, помогите пожалуйста сделать условие при котором в postData будет передаваться в зависимости от значения та или иная переменная с соответствующим идентификатором.

```
function remove(id) {
    var status = $('#status'+id).val();
    var user_id  = $('#userId').val();

    var label  = $('#label').val();

    var postData = {status: status, product_id: id, user_id: user_id, label: label};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: "/control/delete/",
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            if(data['success'] == 1) {
                $('#status'+id).val('');
            } else {
                alert(data['message']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Вот html

```
{foreach $model as $item}

    <h3><a href="/product/pg/{$item.id}/">{$item.product}</a></h3>
    <div id="comraitBlock">
        <div style="width: 1000%">
        <div class="blockComment">
        {if isset($item.comment)}

            {foreach $item.comment as $comt}
                <div id="issetComment">

                    <p>{$comt.content}</p><br><br>

                        <form class="deleteComment" name="delete" action="" method="post">
                            <p>
                                <input id="label_1" type="hidden" name="label" value="1" />
                                <input id="userId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser.id}" />
                                <input id="status{$item.id}" type="hidden" name="status" value="1" />
                                <input type="submit" onclick="remove({$item.id});" value="Удалить" />
                            </p>
                        </form>
                </div>
            {/foreach}

        {else}
            <div id="blockNewComment">
                <form id="formComment" name="comment" action="" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label>Добавить комментарий:</label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea id="contentComm{$item.id}"
                                  onkeydown="return keyDown.call(this,event)"
                                  onchange="value = value.replace(/^\s+/,'')"
                                  required name="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input id="userId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser.id}" />
                        <input id="statusCom" type="hidden" name="status" value="0" />
                        <input type="submit" onclick="newComment({$item.id});" value="Отправить" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>
        <div id="blockRait">
        {if isset($item.rating)}

            {foreach $item.rating as $rait}

                <p><font size="6">{$rait.score}</font></p>
                <form class="deleteRating" name="delete" action="" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <input id="label_2" type="hidden" name="label" value="2" />
                        <input id="userId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser.id}" />
                        <input id="status{$item.id}" type="hidden" name="status" value="1" />
                        <input type="submit" onclick="remove({$item.id});" value="Удалить" />
                    </p>
                </form>

            {/foreach}
        {else}
            <div id="blockNewRait">
                <form id="formRating" name="rating" action="" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label>Оценить:</label>
                        <br>
                        <select id="ratingValue{$item.id}" required name="score">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input id="userId" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{$authUser.id}" />
                        <input id="statusRat" type="hidden" name="status" value="0" />
                        <input type="submit" onclick="newRating({$item.id});" value="Оценить" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        {/if}
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Что значит "в зависимости от значения"? Какая зависимость?

Comment: @vp_arth два почти одинаковых hidden инпута в двух разных формах. Отправленные данные обрабатываются одним контроллером. Два одинаковых действия для разных таблиц в базе, в запросах отличается только названиями этих таблиц.

Comment: Мне сказали что уникальный идентификатор на странице должен быть один.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос... Но я хотел бы порекомендовать вам не рассматривать эти "переменные", как связанные. Не стесняйтесь сделать два независимых запроса, если нужно.

Comment: @phpХ Вам сказали правильно

Comment: @vp_arth Да у меня как раз два разных запроса. Но в ajax хочу использовать одну фунцкию. Не хочу повторять код из-за одной переменной. Эти инпуты отличаются лишь передаваемыми в post значениями: value = "1" or value="2"

Comment: Пометьте это поле иначе, не id, а классом например. И выбирайте его отталкиваясь от текущей формы: `label = $('input.hidden_label', current_form)`

Comment: @vp_arth Опа, а current_form что за функция?

Comment: это та форма, внутри которой находится `'input.hidden_label'`. Вы бы уже показали нормальный код.

Comment: это же всё ещё js.Это просто переменная, в которую вы предварительно положили текущую форму)

Comment: Добавил весь код. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Дело в том что в контроллере все зациклено на этом $_POST['label']. Может алгоритм хреновый, но я бы не хотел возвращаться назад.

Comment: @phpХ как/когда вызывается эта функция? покажите html

Comment: @Igor Добавил html

Answer (score 2):

Можно идентифицировать поля в форме с помощью атрибута `name`:

```js
function send(form) {
  var data = {
    title: form.elements.title.value,
    label: form.elements.label.value,
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="send(this);return false">
  <input name=title value="Form 1">
  <input name=label type=hidden value="1">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>

<form onsubmit="send(this);return false">
  <input name=title value="Form 2">
  <input name=label type=hidden value="2">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```